# include stroke-width in lineargradient X/Y

Tags: svg, linear-gradients

I've run into an issue with linear gradients in that when I'm adding it to a stroke, it doesn't display as it does when applying as a fill. I think this is the issue: [objectBoundingBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBox) where, at the bottom of this section, it says:

> Keyword objectBoundingBox should not be used when the geometry of the applicable element has no width or no height, such as the case of a horizontal or vertical line, even when the line has actual thickness when viewed due to having a non-zero stroke width since stroke width is ignored for bounding box calculations. When the geometry of the applicable element has no width or height and objectBoundingBox is specified, then the given effect (e.g., a gradient or a filter) will be ignored.

Let me show you:

This is what a rect with a fill looks like:

```html
<svg name="scaled1box" overflow="visible" x="12.35" y="12.35" fill="url(#fillLinGrads0sp5)">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="fillLinGrads0sp5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1" >
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#7030A0" />
            <stop offset="0.49" stop-color="#7030A0" />
            <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stop offset="0.51" stop-color="#0070C0" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0070C0" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path d="M0,0L72,0L72,144L0,144Z" />
      </svg>
```

But with a stroke instead:

```html
<svg name="scaled1box" overflow="visible" x="12.375" y="12.375"  fill="none" stroke="url(#strokeLinGrads0sp5)" stroke-width="25" stroke-miterlimit="8">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="strokeLinGrads0sp5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#7030A0" />
            <stop offset="0.49" stop-color="#7030A0" />
            <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stop offset="0.51" stop-color="#0070C0" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0070C0" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path d="M0,0L72,0L72,144L0,144Z" />
      </svg>
```

Notice in the one with the stroke, the "45 degree" angle is off slightly. I believe this has to do with the fact that the bounding box is for the path only, not the path + stroke-width.

Okay, fine. Now what? I still need it to be for the path + stroke+width.

So I tried setting the relative coordinates and couldn't figure out how this would work. Meaning I set increased the rectangle of w=72,h=144 to a square of w=144,h=144 and set the end points of `x2="1"` and `y2="1`" to where they would be relative to the original bounding box - so `x2="1.1736"` and `y2="1.1736`" (1.1736 = new w/h of 169 (144+25 for stroke width) divided by old w/h of 144.). No dice. Then I tried offsetting both start and end points to account for a transform first, then a scale. Again, no dice.

So I went searching. [This seemed really promising](http://w3-org.9356.n7.nabble.com/stroke-gradient-for-lines-or-horizontal-paths-tp145002p145019.html), until I couldn't actually figure out his variables, like eps and the like.

So, when all else failed, I just tried mucking around with numbers. This seems close.

```html
<svg name="scaled1box" overflow="visible" x="12.375" y="12.375" fill="none" stroke="url(#strokeLinGrads0sp5)" stroke-width="25" stroke-miterlimit="8">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="strokeLinGrads0sp5" x1="-0.087" y1="-0.24" x2="1.17" y2="1.17">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#7030A0" />
            <stop offset="0.49" stop-color="#7030A0" />
            <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stop offset="0.51" stop-color="#0070C0" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0070C0" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path d="M0,0L72,0L72,144L0,144Z" />
      </svg>
```

But I'm not sure how to calculate that for all start/end points. It was really just mucking around.

Options:

1. Give up and convert the stroke to a path instead.
2. Get some help from you to figure out how to translate relative or
   absolute point values to accommodate a BB + stroke width using the initial values.

Comment: use userSpaceOnUse units instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson, sure, i tried that, it doesn't work `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="97.5" y2="169"`

Comment: Does you line run from (0,0) to (97.5,169)?  if not, then those linearGradient coordinates are wrong.  You will need to use the same `x1`,`y1`,`x2`,and `y2` from the `<line>`.  And you will need to have one `<linearGradient>` for every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [nice bit of code here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/134) that helps squash the original angle that works like a charm.